# If we have $mr + ns = 1$, how do we prove that $\operatorname{GCD}(m,n) = 1$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cyclic-groups

Prove that greatest common divisor of $m$ and $n$ is $1$ where $m<n$.

[image]

Comment: The theorem "$gcd(m,n)=1\iff\exists r,s: mr+ns=1$" is a fairly well known theorem that your book assumes you already know - this is a sign you should read some more introductory text before reading your current book.

Comment: @5xum : Could you write $\gcd(m,n)$ instead of $gcd(m,n)$? It's just one more keystroke -- a backslash -- and it results in proper spacing in things like $3\gcd(m,n). \qquad$

Comment: Sorry @5xnum, I am just following my college curriculum and this theorem was never mentioned before.

Answer (score 1):

A common factor of m and n would be a factor of mr+ns=1.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If integer $d>0$ divides both $m,n$

$d$ must divide $mr+ns$ for any integers $r,s$

Answer (score 1):

Let $d = \gcd(m,n).$

Then $d$ is a divisor of $m$ and of $n.$

So $da= m$ and $db=n$ for some integers $a,b.$

Therefore $1=mr+ns = (da)r+(db)s = d(ar+bs).$  So $d$ is a divisor of $1.$